# How do I check a whole existing regular expression for a digit?

Tags: regex

I have written a regular expression as follows:

`"^[\+]{0,1}([\#]|[\*]|[\d]){1,15}$"`

In summary this matches an optional '+' sign followed by up to 15 characters which might be '#', '*' or a digit.

However, this means that '+#' will match and this is not a valid result as I always need at least one number.

Typical valid matches might be:

```
+1234
445678999
+#7897897
+345764756#775
```

So, given that I've crafted a valid RegEx for these to match, I guess the elegant solution is to use this regex and add some special criterion to globally check for a digit in the result OR somehow disallow anything which doesn't have at least one digit in.

How do I check for that digit?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but just a couple of minor comments on formatting, that (in my opinion) would make this a bit easier to read. You can replace `{0,1}` with `?`, and the `([\#]|[\*]|[\d])` could be replaced with `[#*\d]`. @Stephan has done this in his answer, which I think probably solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @DaveyDaveDave, I'll take that advice on board.  However, though I considered Stephan's answer at first, I think GsusRecovery's is my preferred solution.  123 seems to think so too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solutions requires at least one digit in the string, using lookahead (the `(?=...)` section):

```
^(?=.*\d)\+?[#*\d]{1,15}$
```

**Legenda**

```
^               # Start of the string (or line with m/multiline flag)             
  (?=.*\d)      # Lookahead that checks for at least one digit in the match
  \+?           # An optional literal plus '+'
  [#*\d]{1,15}  # one to fifteen of literal '#' or '*' or digit (\d is [0-9])
$               # End of the string (line with m/multiline flag)
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI8jH3/2)

**Regex graphical schema** (everybody loves it)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

*NOTE: as you can see in the demo avoid also combinations just like `+*` or `+` or `#*` , you get it...*

Comment: This is the correct answer, stephans is fundamentally incorrect as it doesn't ensure any number is present.

Comment: @123: you're right, i have misread the latest part of OP question (requiring at least one digit) but at the same time i've thought is what he really wants

Comment: Thanks @GsusRecovery I think this is what I'm really after.

Answer (score 5):

Try this regex (my first idea initially):

```
^(?=.*[0-9])[+]?([#*\d]{1,15})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can replace `[0-9]` with `\d`.

**DEMO:**

https://regex101.com/r/bM9oE6/3

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Stephan.  Especially thank you for the very swift response.

Comment: It also matches string without digits like `#*` or `+#*`

Comment: This doesn't ensure a number, it just ensures that `#` is not the last character and would fail on what appears to be valid cases.

Comment: Please check my update with a new demo. It takes into @Toto's remark.

Comment: @Stephan it doesn't take into account mine though, it will fail on valid numbers that end in `#*`

Comment: I agree, this answer is still wrong, and you can't fix it by tweaking the lookbehind some more.  You have to use a lookahead.

Comment: @Stephan: what's the purpose of the capturing group?

Comment: @GsusRecovery I can't respond to this question. Only OP knows.

Comment: @Stephan: i see you carry it from the original regex. Probably Rodent use the round brackets only to use alternation (not strictly needed in this case)

Comment: Hi guys, firstly, I am using the principle of the lookahead concept which I wasn't aware of previously to solve my problem now with some slight mods to GsusRecovery's solution - so I have my answer(thanks).  Purpose:it represents a telephone number which could also be a SIP identity.  So using python phonenumbers library (Google) is not sufficient to check for a valid phone number as I also want to support short numbers.  The exact regex requirement is evolving the more developers I speak to who are involved at different layers in the system I'm working with.

Comment: by SIP identity I mean the 1st part of a SIP address; i.e. the bit before the @ sign.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

```
^(?=.*\d)\+?[#*\d]{1,15}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  (?=           : lookahead
    .*\d        : at least one digit
  )
  \+?           : optional +
  [#*\d]{1,15}  : 1 to 15 character in class [#*\d]
$               : end of line
```

**matched:**

```
+1234
445678999
+#7897897
+345764756#775
###456
```

**not matched:**

```
+#*
+*
#*
+#
```

Comment: it's better to put the lookahead at the beginning of the regex to avoid some backtracking: this version is ``~15%`` slower (93 steps against 80 steps)

Answer (score -2):

This should work in your case:

```
^(\+{0,1}[\d#]{1,15})$
```

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/fU1eC2/1

**Edit:**

If you need # after + in string use `^[+#]?([\d#]{1,15})(?<!#)$`
matches "+`#7897897`"

If don't, use `^[+#]*([\d#]{1,15})(?<!#)$`
matches "+#`7897897`"

Comment: This accepts `+#`, which is what the question is asking to avoid.